# How to rename a directory?

Tags: ruby, file-io

How do I rename a directory in Ruby?
I see how to rename individual files, but not folders.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`FileUtils.mv old_name, new_name`

Check the [docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/mv) for more info

Comment: Didn't work for me for folders in some cases. `File.rename` worked.

Comment: By.chance do you have an example of when it doesn't work. Im curious as I can't see anything special looking at the source.

Comment: From my book it says for `FileUtils.mv`, if `new_name` is a directory, `old_name` will be moved into that directory.

Comment: This is correct, just as the unix mv command does. Provided new_name is a directory and exists. But if this is the case rename will throw an error (provided the directory is non empty). I'm curious as to when mv will fail but rename will work as @miguelSantirso said. Interestingly mv uses rename in 1.9.3.

Comment: One instance where `File.rename` works and `FileUtils.mv` fails is when you try to rename a directory with the same name or (on case-insensitive filesystems) with a name that differs only in case. `FileUtils.mv` tries to move the directory inside itself whereas `File.rename` complies.

Answer (score 28):

`File.rename` will let you rename directories:

```
File.rename './my-directory', './my-renamed-directory'
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. According to http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000019, doesn't File.rename only work for files and not directories?

Comment: @yoyoyo: It'll work for directories, too. (Think of a directory as a special case of a file.)

Comment: It refuses to rename not empty directories (ruby 2.2.1). ``FileUtils`` could do this

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mv sourcedir, newdir
```